# How to solve IONIC 4 CORS issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm currently working on a greenfield project with IONIC 4 and I'm experimenting a CORS issue while trying to access an external API:

*Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.*

I've tried already two approaches as described on its document (https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors):

1) Use the HTTP plugin from Ionic Native to make the requests natively from outside the webview. It seems the most reasonable solution but I went through some issues with OkHTTP versions and I was not able to fix it.

2) Use a proxy config. Also tried to create a proxy file and for some reason it has not translated the call correctly.

Does anybody has a good solution for this issue? Spending hours on this with no solution.

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.7 (/home/mauricio/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1 
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.13.0 (/home/mauricio/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.12.0
   OS     : Linux 4.15

Cordova plugins:
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

Comment: If you just want to enable it for the localhost you can use chrome extension for that

Comment: are you using  'http://localhost:8100' as a server url from your application?

Comment: I cannot use the chrome extension for that, since I would like to use it on the mobile device.

Comment: I'm using localhost:8100 as the local server for front end app. I do not have control over the backend API.